# Starting the Hat Dash with the up arrow instead of space causes the game to behave oddly

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

If I use the up arrow key on my keyboard to start the Hat Dash game, the game behaves a little oddly. First off, the second line of the road - that's not there when you haven't started - doesn't appear when you press up. The "press space to start" line doesn't go away, and the score counter doesn't appear... but the game still plays.

But it gets much faster much more quickly than starting with space (as in, the speed of the game increases at a faster pace), although that's just anecdotal evidence based on the list of high scores and the time those took.

Here's a GIF that shows what happens when you start the game with the up key (and then press space to jump in the middle):

[image: GIF illustrating the problem]

Answer (score 1):

The arrow key now behaves the same as space when starting the game (but I am not going to change the "Press space to start message").

> up-arrow or space
> both the same now in our eyes
> when used for init